# Graph - Adjacency List solved as Linked List

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, linked-list, adjacency-list

What does this line do?

```
node.next = self.graph[src]
```

**EX: [1:2]**
here I know how to make 2 as a node, then make index 1 equal it, but what if i have [1:3] too, how to add 3 to 2?

Here's the full code of Adjacency List implementation

```
class AdjNode:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.vertex = data
        self.next = None
        

class Graph:
    def __init__(self, vertices):
        self.vertices = vertices
        self.graph = [None] * self.vertices
        
    def add_edge(self, src, dest):
        node = AdjNode(dest)
#==================================================
        node.next = self.graph[src]
#==================================================
        self.graph[src] = node
        
        
    def print_graph(self):
        for i in range(self.vertices):
            print("Adjacency list of vertex {}\n {}".format(i,i), end="")
            temp = self.graph[i]
            while temp:
                print(" -> {}".format(temp.vertex), end="")
                temp = temp.next
            print(" \n")              
        

V = 5
graph = Graph(V)
graph.add_edge(0, 1)
graph.add_edge(0, 4)
graph.add_edge(1, 2)
graph.add_edge(1, 3)
graph.add_edge(1, 4)
graph.add_edge(2, 3)
graph.add_edge(3, 4)

graph.print_graph()
```

**Output**

```
Adjacency list of vertex 0
 0 -> 4 -> 1 

Adjacency list of vertex 1
 1 -> 4 -> 3 -> 2 

Adjacency list of vertex 2
 2 -> 3 

Adjacency list of vertex 3
 3 -> 4 

Adjacency list of vertex 4
 4
```

Comment: `node.next = self.graph[src]` is meant to collect all the vertices adjancent to a vertex in a vertex-indexed `list` of `list`s, which, in this particular case, is the `graph` member of the `Graph` class. Additionally, `self.graph[src] = node` maintains a link to the head of the list.

Comment: @ArnabDe
Thanks I got that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> EX: [1:2] here I know how to make 2 as a node, then make index 1 equal it, but what if i have [1:3] too, how to add 3 to 2?

It may help to visualise the process. So let's say there are four nodes, numbered 0, 1, 2 and 3, then we have `self.graph` initialised as follows (boxes are accessed by index):

```
               self.graph
                    ↓
┌─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┐
│ 0: None │ 1: None │ 2: None │ 3: None │
└─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┘
```

Let's say `graph.add_edge(1, 2)` would be the first action on that graph, so then `src` is 1 and `dst` is 2. The first statement `node = AdjNode(dest)` will bring this state:

```
               self.graph
                    ↓
┌─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┐
│ 0: None │ 1: None │ 2: None │ 3: None │
└─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┘
          
        ┌────────────┐
 node → │ vertex: 2  │
        │ next: None │ 
        └────────────┘
```

The next statement `node.next = self.graph[src]` doesn't do much now, as it just assigns `None` to `node.next`, which is already there. Finally, `graph[src] = node` *does* make an important link:

```
               self.graph
                    ↓
┌─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┐
│ 0: None │ 1: ─┐   │ 2: None │ 3: None │
└─────────┴─────│───┴─────────┴─────────┘
                │
                │
                │
                ▼
        ┌────────────┐
 node → │ vertex: 2  │
        │ next: None │ 
        └────────────┘
```

Then the function returns, and `node` is no longer a name that is in scope.

Now, let's look at what `graph.add_edge(1, 3)` does. So `src` is 1 again, but `dst` is 3. The usual node is created with `node = AdjNode(dest)` giving this state (with a *new* `node` name for the new node):

```
               self.graph
                    ↓
┌─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┐
│ 0: None │ 1: ─┐   │ 2: None │ 3: None │
└─────────┴─────│───┴─────────┴─────────┘
  node          │
   ↓            │
 ┌────────────┐ │
 │ vertex: 3  │ │
 │ next: None │ │
 └────────────┘ │
                ▼
        ┌────────────┐
        │ vertex: 2  │
        │ next: None │ 
        └────────────┘
```

And now the "magic" assignment happens: `node.next = self.graph[src]`. This will copy the *reference* that is at `self.graph[src]` into `node.next`. In the image that means the arrow is copied so that they point to the same thing:

```
               self.graph
                    ↓
┌─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┐
│ 0: None │ 1: ─┐   │ 2: None │ 3: None │
└─────────┴─────│───┴─────────┴─────────┘
  node          │
   ↓            │
 ┌────────────┐ │
 │ vertex: 3  │ │
 │ next: ─┐   │ │
 └────────│───┘ │
          ▼     ▼
        ┌────────────┐
        │ vertex: 2  │
        │ next: None │ 
        └────────────┘
```

And finally, we execute `graph[src] = node`:

```
               self.graph
                    ↓
┌─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┐
│ 0: None │ 1: ─┐   │ 2: None │ 3: None │
└─────────┴─────│───┴─────────┴─────────┘
        node    │
         ↓      ▼
      ┌────────────┐ 
      │ vertex: 3  │ 
      │ next: ─┐   │
      └────────│───┘
               ▼
        ┌────────────┐
        │ vertex: 2  │
        │ next: None │ 
        └────────────┘
```

So, after all this, the *later* destination node was *prefixed* to a linked list before the node(s) that were already in the list that started at `self.graph[src]`.

I hope this clarifies it.